# How to untar directory to specific directory on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i trying to untar directory to specific directory that tar file is selected from UI after that i want to change the current dir to specific dir their i want to untar that directory.while doing that after passing that dir to rails server complete name will be change. how can i untar that directory(name changed dir) to specfic directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system("UNZIP source_file_path destination_path /X")
```

system function executes whatever you can entered in terminal/cmd prompt 
try to untar files in com prompt / terminal first when you got your required command just pass it to system function of rails it will execute that

when form is posted with files rails / server store that file temporary and in params you get the path for same file just google how to get path I am not sure